# How to reduce join operation to a single row in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join

This example is *invented* for the purpose of the question.

```
SELECT 
    PR.PROVINCE_NAME 
    ,CO.COUNTRY_NAME
FROM
    PROVINCE PR
    JOIN COUNTRY CO ON CO.COUNTRY_ID=PR.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE
    PR.PROVINCE_ID IN (1,2)
```

Let's assume that `COUNTRY_ID` is not the Primary Key in the Country table and the above join on Country table returns potentially multiple rows. We don't know how many rows and we don't care why there are multiple ones. We only want to join on one of them, so we get one row per Province.

I tried subquery for the join but can't pass in `PR.COUNTRY_ID` for Oracle 11.2. Are there any other ways that this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical *safe* approach of handling tables without PK is to extend the duplicated column with a unique index (row_numer of the duplicated row)

In your case this would be:

```
with COUNTRY_UNIQUE as (
select COUNTRY_ID, 
row_number() over (partition by COUNTRY_ID  order by COUNTRY_NAME) rn,
COUNTRY_NAME
from country)
select * from COUNTRY_UNIQUE 
order by COUNTRY_ID, rn;
```

leading to

```
COUNTRY_ID         RN COUNTRY_NAME
---------- ---------- ------------
         1          1 C1           
         2          1 C2           
         2          2 C3
```

The combination of `COUNTRY_ID`and `RN` is unique, so if you constraint only `RN = 1` the `COUNTRY_ID` is unique.
You may define the order of the duplicated records and control with it the selection - in our case we choose the smalest COUNTRY_NAME.

The whole join used this subquery and constraints the countries on `RN = 1`

```
with COUNTRY_UNIQUE as (
select COUNTRY_ID, 
row_number() over (partition by COUNTRY_ID  order by COUNTRY_NAME) rn,
COUNTRY_NAME
from country)
SELECT 
    PR.PROVINCE_NAME 
    ,CO.COUNTRY_NAME
FROM
    PROVINCE PR
    JOIN COUNTRY_UNIQUE CO ON CO.COUNTRY_ID=PR.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE
    PR.PROVINCE_ID IN (1,2) 
    AND CO.RN = 1;  /* consider only unique countries */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Oracle 12c, you can use a `LATERAL` view in the join.  Like this:

```
SELECT
    PR.PROVINCE_NAME 
    ,CO.COUNTRY_NAME
FROM
    PROVINCE PR
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL ( 
       SELECT * FROM COUNTRY CO 
       WHERE CO.COUNTRY_ID=PR.COUNTRY_ID 
       FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) CO 
WHERE
    PR.PROVINCE_ID IN (1,2)
```

#### Update for Oracle 11.2

In Oracle 11.2, you can use something along these lines.  Depending on the size of `COUNTRY` and how many duplicates there are per `COUNTRY_ID`, it could perform as well or better than the 12c approach.  (Fewer buffer gets but more memory required).

```
SELECT pr.province_name,
       co.country_name
FROM   province pr
       INNER JOIN (SELECT *
                   FROM   (SELECT co.*,
                                  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY co.country_id ORDER BY co.country_name) rn
                           FROM   country co)
                   WHERE  rn = 1) co
         ON co.country_id = pr.country_id
WHERE  pr.province_id IN (1, 2)
```